# Remove sub-menu span in wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have a piece of HTML menu which I want to display in Wordpress with wp_nav_menu.

The HTML

```
<nav id="navigation" class="ddsmoothmenu">
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="current"><span>Home</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index-2.html">Home Alternate 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-3.html">Home Alternate 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-4.html">Home Alternate 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-5.html">Home Alternate 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-6.html">Home Alternate 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

I am adding the following in my Wordpress header.php file to display the nav menu

```
$defaults = array(
               'theme_location'  => 'primary',
               'menu'            => 'Primary Menu',
               'container'       => '',
               'container_class' => '',
               'container_id'    => '',
               'menu_class'      => 'menu',
               'menu_id'         => '',
               'echo'            => true,
               'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
               'before'          => '',
               'after'           => '',
               'link_before'     => '<span>',
               'link_after'      => '</span>',
               'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
               'depth'           => 0,
               'walker'          => ''
             );
wp_nav_menu($defaults);
```

However the output is adding the  tags also in the second level of the menu items as

```
<nav id="navigation" class="ddsmoothmenu">
<ul id="main-menu">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="current"><span>Home</span></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index-2.html"><span>Home Alternate 2</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="index-3.html"><span>Home Alternate 3</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="index-4.html"><span>Home Alternate 4</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="index-5.html"><span>Home Alternate 5</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="index-6.html"><span>Home Alternate 6</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Is there a way to add the span only for the top level menu item or remove the spans from the second level items?

Comment: One way is to write your own Walker class (that modifies the default one): http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/understanding-the-walker-class/

Comment: Thanks Calle. It surely is a way, though I seem to have found an easier option with jQuery. Will post the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', function( $items ) {
      foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if (!$item->menu_item_parent) {
           $item->title = '<span>' . $item->title . '</span>';
        }
    }
    return $items;
});
```

Comment: That adds an additional span to the parent item somehow and does not remove the span for the sub-menu item.

Comment: You need to set your link_before and link_after to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, While walker seems to be one good way of getting this done, it seems to be pretty elaborate with many lines of codes. I just found out that the easiest way to remove the span for the sub-menu items is with jQuery. Wordpress automatically adds the sub-menu class to the child ul and hence what worked for me was

```
$('ul.sub-menu li a span').contents().unwrap();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS you can hide the sub-menu of `wp_nav_menu`

```
.sub-menu { display:none; }
```